How to prevent Pop OS! from automatically reverting kernels when switching to hybrid graphics?
I am using Pop Os 22.04. The default boot kernel of this OS was 6.9.3-76060903-generic. However, I needed to switch to an older kernel 6.5.0-25-generic in order to properly run VMWare workstation, which is a necessity for my case. Possibly because of some random updates, my kernel got reverted to the default one. I switched back to the 6.5 kernel using the kernelstub tutorial. However now, it seems like the machine is only running on Integrated Graphics (I am using a laptop with integrated Intel graphics + an RTX 2070). This mode does not support an external monitor via HDMI (also a necessity).
Whenever I try to switch to Hybrid or Dedicated Graphics mode via the system76-power utility, my kernel reverts back to the 6.9.xx one. How to resolve this??
